# How do I change or set a specific author name for my comments on Microsoft Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, user-accounts, comments, authoring

My computer's local account name is "Keekee123".

When I give comments on Microsoft word documents, this user name automatically shows up as the author of my comments on this computer. How can I change it by default so whenever I give comments in a Word document it will use a different name such as "John Oliver"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, click “Review” tab.

Then click “Track Change” in “Tracking” group.

Next, click “Change User Name”.

[image]

Now the “Word Options” dialog box will pop up. Make sure the “General” tab is displayed. Then change the user name and initials.

Finally, click “OK”.

[image]

This change will affect all future documents.

For the comments made before the change, they keep the original names.

Comment: I don't get that 'change user name' option in my Track Changes menu. I had to click on the little downward arrow in the lower-right corner of the track changes pane, and that opened a dialog box to for Track Change options. Then click 'Advanced Options', or you might have a 'Change user name' option there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged into MS Office, you may have a checkbox underneath the Initials field that says: "Always use these values regardless of sign in to Office" - make sure that box is checked or the comments will show up as the name you are signed in as.

Answer (score 0):

The method from the correct answer has slightly changed.

[1-minute VIDEO INSTRUCTION](https://youtu.be/fIrMuBaxyhk) in case you want to see the procedure in more detail.

Textual instruction:

1. Go to the "Review" tab and in the "Tracking" section, click on the little arrow in the bottom right corner

[image]

2. In the new window, click on "Change User Name" which will open the Word Options

[image]

3. In the options, you'll have to set a desired user name **AND** check the box which says *"Always use these values regardless of sign in to Office"*.

[image]

4. After confirming your changes with "OK", all new comments will have the custom user name

Note: While you can't change the user names of already existing comments, you can at least make all the comments anonymous, if this is your reason for changing the comments in the first place. For that, go to "File" > "Info" > "Check for Issues" > "Inspect Document" and then inspect for "Comments, Revision and Versions" and after Word finds them, select "Remove All". Once you save the document and reopen it, all comments will be anonymized. Again, you'll find all these visualized instructions in the linked video .